# How to use series in the GR-tensor package?

Tags: maple

How can I use the series command for a specific quantity to find it up to a certain order of magnitude?

Is it possible to have an expanded series of a tensor in `GR-tensor` package?

Comment: I slightly improved formatting of your question. But in order to receive helpful answers, you might want to do some more research and then include your own efforts in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can apply series expansion to an object using the grmap() command.

The help for this function gives an example:

e.g. to do a taylor series expansion about r=a to second order

grmap(R(dn,dn,dn,dn), taylor, 'x',r=a,2);

See the help for grmap: ?grmap

Comment: @petem: Thank U. I tried it, however, it shows a matrix and the components are determined as $$O(\epsilon^2)$$ and so on. The full form of components cannot be seen :/

Comment: Can you please send the worksheet to the support email? grtensor3@gmail.com